# Saving feature in mind mapping tool

Tags: c++, qt, save, qmake, mindmapping

I've been working with friends for some time on a mind map program. Generally, the whole program is already set up, but we still lack a module that will save the map project in jpg or in a format for reopening the edition, etc. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to go about it and what is the best way to use it? We use the latest version of QT Qmake/C++

In general, I watched a few videos related to saving programs and there was nothing insightful in them. More like a lack of sense

Comment: @SamVarshavchik we are building a mind map generator such as you can find on a internet. As I said everything is working except saving tool. We want it to work just like paint word etc. so you can save as jpg this map or either save it In a form that we can edit it later.

Comment: A brief search on what this is, suggests that this is a highly specialized, boutique, technical area. I don't think you have very good chances of finding someone else on Stackoverflow who is familiar with this topic. The tag itself has only 31 followers, and doesn't have any description, even. Unless this question has something specific related to this, it will benefit from having it restated to ask something ***specific** related to only C++ or Qt. In terms of the very broad "how to save an image file", the answer would be: learn the relevant Qt or library API documentation.